# Need drop-downs option value in form action query-string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am working in PHP + HTML

I have a form with the action defined like so:

1] Form action="index.php?option=com_advertisment&task=keysearch&Itemid=2&catid=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value"

but the selected value of drop down is not shown in query string when I submit the form.

That means `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value` is not replace by `value` but comes as it is in query string like this:

> http://mydemoserver.com/index.php?option=com_advertisment&task=keysearch&Itemid=2&catid=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value

If any one know the solution please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You are probably mixing javascript and HTML, but without any source code it's hard to tell. Please post an example (jsfiddle) that demonstrates what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to mix your HTML and JS incorrectly.

If you have your `<form>` tag simply put all your fields inside of the tag.

If you want the first three query-parameter pairs to be static, you can write them inside of hidden `<input>` tags.

For example:

```
<form action = "index.php" method = "GET">

<input type = "hidden" name = "option" value = "com_advertisment" />
<input type = "hidden" name = "task" value = "keysearch" />
<input type = "hidden" name = "Itemid" value = "2" />

<select name = "catid">
    <option value = "1">Some option</option>
    <option value = "2">Another option</option>
</select>

<input type = "submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given `name` attribute to your dropdown/select box.

`eg. <select name="foobar"><option value='first'>First</option></select>`

and change the action attribute of your `<form>` to `index.php` only and `method='get'`

so once your submit your form, all the data will be sent to your php page (index.php in this case) via get method and you can fetch the data using `$_GET['foobar']`.